# how to call winmain function through a main function

Tags: winapi

I am using dev c++ and i need to call a function which has some butons and edit boxes created using windows.h through another program which uses graphics functions and both files exist in a project and i am unable to do it..can any one help me please...

Comment: Why are you using Dev C++? It is pants, and there are numerous far superior alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, you have a function that creates some GUI components and needs to be called from two different programs. If this is the case, one option is to create a separate .DLL project that makes a run-time library that can be shared with the other two programs.